# Makefile always recompiling a file

Tags: c++, c, makefile, gnu-make

I am learning how to set up makefiles, and have ran into a problem. To demonstrate this I have created a simple "project" consisting of source files `main.m` and `test.m`.

I am trying to setup make to compile these files (only if somethings changed), and store the object files in somewhere else (here `build/`)

My Makefile:

```
OBJ = ./build

SOURCES=main.m test.m
OBJECTS=$(addprefix $(OBJ)/,$(SOURCES:.m=.o))
EXECUTABLE=test

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
        gcc $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXECUTABLE)

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJ)/%.o: %.m build/
        gcc -c $< -o $@

build/:
        mkdir build
```

When I run it for the first time (with only the Makefile and the sources in the current directory) it does what I expect it to do:

```
gcc -c main.m -o build/main.o
gcc -c test.m -o build/test.o
gcc ./build/main.o ./build/test.o -o test
```

However if I run `make` again:

```
gcc -c main.m -o build/main.o
gcc ./build/main.o ./build/test.o -o test
```

What have I done wrong? Also noting any other errors in the Makefile is appreciated, as I am trying to learn to create "good" Makefiles.

EDIT:

What I spotted from `make -d`:

```
Finished prerequisites of target file `build/main.o'.
Prerequisite `main.m' is older than target `build/main.o'.
Prerequisite `build/' is older than target `build/main.o'.
No need to remake target `build/main.o'.
```

and

```
Finished prerequisites of target file `build/test.o'.
Prerequisite `test.m' is older than target `build/test.o'.
Prerequisite `build/' is newer than target `build/test.o'.
Must remake target `build/test.o'.
```

Comment: I think you just don't want the `/` attached to `build` in a couple of places.  Let me try it out here.  You can use `make -d` to see how `make` is making its decisions about what to build, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. However the `make -d` route is going to take a while as it output 927 lines of information :)

Comment: You can quiet that down by getting rid of as many implicit rules as posisble.  I just tried your makefile here though with a simple test project, and it seemed to work as expected.  That is, on the second run, I just get `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`.

Comment: @CarlNorum It seems to have something to do with the build/ folder, see my edit to the Q

Comment: Yup.  I see that.  Answered below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `make -d` output shows that `make` thinks your build directory has been updated, and so that file needs to be rebuilt.

I guess that happens because some operation either on your build system's part or by something else in your filesystem is causing some timestamp on that directory to be updated.

You can fix the problem by making `build` an *order-only prerequisite* by adding a `|` to that rule:

```
$(OBJECTS): $(OBJ)/%.o: %.m | build
```

I deleted the `/` too, since it wasn't doing anything.

Since you asked, some other editorial notes:

1. Add a `clean` target.  Something like:

   ```
   clean:
       rm -rf $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJ)
   ```
2. You don't need the `./` when you set `OBJ`.  Just `OBJ = build` is enough.
3. You don't need the `/` on `build` as mentioned above.  But that doesn't really matter, since you shouldn't be referring it to it anyway.  Repalce `build` with `$(OBJ)` wherever you see it.
4. `mkdir` will fail if the directory already exists.  You probably should prefix that command with a `-`:

   ```
   $(OBJ):
       -mkdir $(OBJ)
   ```

   Note that I've done the replacement with `$(OBJ)` that I mentioned in #3 above.
5. Auto-generation of dependencies is very helpful.  Your project as shown isn't big enough to really need it, but it's easy enough to add, so why not.  You'll need to do a couple of things.  First, get the appropriate dependency file names:

   ```
   DEPFILES = $(addprefix $(OBJ)/,$(SOURCES:.m=.d))
   ```

   Then get the compiler to generate them by adding the `-MMD` flag:

   ```
   gcc -MMD -c $< -o $@
   ```

   Lastly, include them in your makefile if they're available, by adding a line at the end of your makefile:

   ```
   -include $(DEPFILES)
   ```

Comment: So it was basically `make` creating the object files in `build/` that caused it to update and force recompile?

Comment: Seems that way.  That doesn't happen on my machine, but I guess that behaviour could be filesystem-dependent.

Comment: Or it could also have something to do with the mount parameters, mainly the ones telling it when it should update timestamps.

Comment: Also: What does make do if there is a file `build` and the directory `build/`. Or there is the file but the dir is not there?

Comment: You can't have both there, the filesystem won't allow it.  If there's a file but not the directory, you'll end up with trouble.  It's probably not worth putting a workaround into the makefile for that, though.

Comment: Also - edited answer with lots more ideas about how to clean up your makefile.

Comment: Thank you for the notes! My real project is also somewhat bigger, and I just created that to act as an demonstration. I also already had the `clean:` target, but just decided to leave it out as it was not important for my main problem. Others I will put to use :)

Comment: All UNIX filesystems behave the same way WRT directory timestamps.  The timestamp of the directory changes whenever the directory itself changes: that means whenever a file is added, removed, or renamed in the directory.  Changing an already-existing file in the directory won't change the directory timestamp (unless your editor creates temporary files for backup or similar).  Obviously this means using a directory as a make rule prerequisite is almost never what you want (although it can be handy if what you want is to know whether or not any files have been created, deleted, or renamed).